# Is energy not a function of space (time-independent Schrödinger equation)?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation

The explicit [time-independent Schrödinger equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#Time-independent_equation) (single nonrelativistic particle) is

> $$
> \bigg[\frac{-\hbar^2}{2\mu}\nabla^2+V(\mathbf{r})\bigg]\Psi(\mathbf r)=E\Psi(\mathbf r)
> $$
>   I guess $\mathbf r$ is a constant vector, i.e. $\mathbf r=(x,y,z)$ in three dimensions.

But is $E$ really a constant? Isn't it a function of space, i.e. $E=E(\mathbf r)$?

Comment: No. It is the constant that apears when separating variables of the time dependent Schrodinger equation. Though there are cases in which the eigenenergies may change in space. Mainly in solid state physics.

Comment: ItcIs not at the core of quantum?

Comment: It might, or might not, be meaningful to you that in classical mechanics, the sum of the kinetic and potential energies is constant, especially evident in the Hamiltonian formulation?

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the time-independent Schrodinger equation is to look for solutions with *constant* energy, so $E$ is *assumed* constant.  Initially $E$ is unknown but one can **only** obtain solutions that satisfy the boundary conditions for selected values of $E$ (often discrete).  Hence solving for the allowed $\Psi(\boldsymbol{\vec r})$ also produces a set of allowed $E$'s, and each allowed $E$ can be paired to an allowed  $\Psi(\boldsymbol{\vec r})$.

Note that in general energy is conserved so $E$ does NOT depend on $\boldsymbol{\vec r}$.

Answer (score 0):

No, E is a constant. Generally speaking, the equation has solutions for only certain values of E (the eigenvalues of the equation). Those values depend on quantum numbers, but they do not depend on spatial coordinates.

BTW, $\vec{r}$ is *not* a constant vector: every point in space corresponds to a different $\vec{r}$.

Comment: With a constant vector I mean a vector $\mathbf r=(x,y,z)\in\mathbb R^3$ and not a vector function $\mathbf r :\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 0):

No, the equation reflects the fact that energy is conserved. If a particle has an energy, E, then in the absence of any interactions the energy will remain E. The distribution of E between KE and PE will vary- that's suggested by the left hand side of the equation which shows a potential varying over space.